# Python Flask - set-Cookie not received by fetch/ajax request because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cookies, http-headers

So I'm trying to do the following (inside html template):

1. Send fetch request to `/foo/bar/1`, which modifies `session` object in Flask, and in turn, should send `set-Cookie` header.
2. Send fetch request to `/foo2/bar2/`, which should use new cookie. (which means `session` object from flask should be updated)

When I check via browser, after request is sent via `fetch`, it contains `set-Cookie` (Response cookies are different than request cookies)

But, when I try to perform second fetch request, it still uses old cookies.

If I try to perform fetch manually, via console in browser, it sets cookie correctly, and later uses correct one.

What's more, when I try to print all the headers after first fetch request (via `console.log(...response.headers);`), it doesn't contain `set-Cookie` header

my fetch look as following (included in html template, as button.onclick function):

```js
fetch(`/foo/bar/1`, {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
  }).then(function (response, status){
    console.log(...response.headers);
})
```

Headers that I am receiving is:

```
['access-control-allow-origin', '*']
['content-length', '1113']
['content-type', 'application/json']
['date', 'Wed, 02 Feb 2022 10:52:56 GMT']
['server', 'Werkzeug/2.0.1 Python/3.9.6']
['vary', 'Cookie']
```

But `Network` tab shows there should be another `set-Cookie` header, which is missing.
According to [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials) this is to be expected, because of the fragment

`Also note that any Set-Cookie response header in a response would not set a cookie if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value in that response is the "*" wildcard rather an actual origin.`

My questions is: How can I change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from wildcard to actual origin?
I've tried setting origins in flask via CORS:

```py
CORS(app, origins=["http://127.0.0.1/:5000"], supports_credentials=True)
```

But this didn't help, and I'm still getting same `Access-Control-Allow-Origin="*"`

Another question is: Maybe I'm trying to overdo something there, and there is simpler solution to initial problem? What confuses me, is why when I am doing request manually in browser console, it sets cookie correctly (despite not having set-Cookie header when trying to print the headers, and having wildcard at `access-control-allow-origin`)

EDIT:
apparently even after having correct `access-control-allow-origin` (non-wildcard), my cookie is still not set and reused in the following requests. My current workaround is just calling endpoint `/foo2/bar2/` with extra argument `1` and then calling `/foo/bar/1` method, but I'm not happy with that.